# How to get left click to work on column visibility example using the Vaadin Flow Grid example

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

On the Column Visibility example on https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/ds/components/grid/#column-visibility the code shows a class `ColumnToggleContextMenu` which isn't part of the Vaadin API however it seems to somehow adjust how the button is hooked so that it can be left clicked rather than the default right click for a context menu. With that in mind the code below will only show the context menu on a right click, I cannot get it to work like the example code. My code is:

```
Button showHideColumnsButton = new Button("Show/Hide Columns");
showHideColumnsButton.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.LUMO_TERTIARY);

ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu(showHideColumnsButton);
for(Grid.Column column : grid.getColumns()) {
    contextMenu.addItem(getColumnName(column), e -> showHideColumn(column));
}
```

I'm considering using a MenuBar instead to see if that will work but I'd prefer to figure out how to use a Button if possible as that seems more appropriate (mainly because it allows the checkbox to show if a column is visible or hidden).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make the context menu to open on left click use `setOpenOnClick(true)`:

```
Button showHideColumnsButton = new Button("Show/Hide Columns");
showHideColumnsButton.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.LUMO_TERTIARY);

ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu(showHideColumnsButton);
contextMenu.setOpenOnClick(true)
for(Grid.Column column : grid.getColumns()) {
    contextMenu.addItem(getColumnName(column), e -> showHideColumn(column));
}
```